# Subsequent calls on startAsync() method

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, request

I'm studying about java servlets, and asynchronous requests right now. And I don't understand the oracle documentation regarding subsequent calls to this method ([`startAsync()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#startAsync%28%29)). First I'll copy it and then I'll explain my doubt.

> This method clears the list of AsyncListener instances (if any) that were registered with the AsyncContext returned by the previous call to one of the startAsync methods, after calling each AsyncListener at its onStartAsync method.
>
> Subsequent invocations of this method, or its overloaded variant, will return the same AsyncContext instance, reinitialized as appropriate.

It says that subsequent invocation of this method will return the same AsyncContext instance. But when I try to do that I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ServletRequest.startAsync called again without any asynchronous dispatch, or called outside the scope of any such dispatch, or called again within the scope of the same dispatch

So, can you please give me an example of how could be a subsequent call to this method without throwing an exception?